# How to place a div below another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Yes, I know, this has been asked many times before. None of the other solutions fix my problem, however.

I want the "register" div to slide down underneath the "container" div, but it appears next to it.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .container
  {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00ffcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
  }
  .register
  {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff0066;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
    clear: left;
  }
  .background
  {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="container text-center" id="container">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>
          Username:
        </p>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <p>
          Password:
        </p>
        <input name="pw" type="password" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="register">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="register text-center">
      <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <p>
          Username:
        </p>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <p>
          Password:
        </p>
        <input name="pw" type="password" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").delay(75).fadeIn(250);
    $("#register").click(function(){
      $(".register").slideToggle();
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I go about fixing this problem (and feel free to give me tips on how to clean up my terrible css!)? Thanks.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `flex-direction` for `display: flex` is `row` - that will put items side-by-side horizontally. To make them display on top of one another, like a column, use `flex-direction: column`

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .container
  {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00ffcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
  }
  .register
  {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff0066;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
    clear: left;
  }
  .background
  {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="container text-center" id="container">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>
          Username:
        </p>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <p>
          Password:
        </p>
        <input name="pw" type="password" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="register">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="register">
        Register
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").delay(75).fadeIn(250);
    $("#register").click(function(){
      $(".register").slideToggle();
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, now the first div appears at the top of the page instead of the centre, which is why I made it flex in the first place. How do I fix this?

Comment: @billofbong ah sorry about that, you use `justify-content: center;` in a `flex-direction: column` layout to center something vertically. edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

change `flex-direction` to column, the default is row which means all flex items will appear in one row horizontally.

You will need to change `align-items` to `justify-content`, since the effect of those 2 is swapped when switching from row to column.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .container
  {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00ffcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
  }
  .register
  {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff0066;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
    clear: left;
  }
  .background
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /*add*/
    justify-content: center; /*changed from align-items*/
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="container text-center" id="container">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>
          Username:
        </p>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <p>
          Password:
        </p>
        <input name="pw" type="password" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="register">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="register">
        Register
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").delay(75).fadeIn(250);
    $("#register").click(function(){
      $(".register").slideToggle();
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```